# google maps ground overlay for flutter web app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, maps, cross-platform

I want to put a ground overlay over a certain lat long location on flutter google map on web app like the picture below can anyone help me to find a solution for that ?

is there any GitHub pr for that or any one done that before ?

and if there is no way to achieve this with flutter can i make it lets say with angular and then integrate this part in flutter code using something like web view ?

[image]

Comment: I think this flutter package can be to help. https://pub.dev/packages/google_static_maps_controller

Comment: @TobyLoby i saw it not sure where is the overlay image is